# How to determine attachment being dragged during Outlook Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, outlook, outlook-addin

I have an outlook add in that involves implementing drag and drop into a WPF control within the Outlook UI.  As part of this I have to be able to drag and drop Attachments off emails.

I have tried doing this using the AttachmentSelection property of the Outlook Inspector and Explorer depending on where the drag has been initiated from but I have run into problems.

This approach works when the attachment has been selected before dragging, or when more than one attachment is dragged out of the one email, but when there is just one attachment being dragged, and the user drags without selecting it first, the AttachmentSelection property is empty.

I have tried to get the attachment information from the DragEventArgs as part of the OnDrop event but there is nothing there of use that I can see.

The behaviour I am trying to replicate exists in Outlook when moving around built in folders and PST stores.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use whatever DragEventArgs provides. There won't be `CF_HDROP` since there is no file system file, but `FileGroupDescriptor` / `FileGroupDescriptorW` will be there.